# Why this code compiles in java?

Tags: java

I can see below code compiles in Java but could not understand what could be the reason?

```
public class test {


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        abc:System.out.println(9);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this java code. here abc is used as a label.

Answer (score 4):

The line in your `main` is a [labelled statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7).

These labels aren't much use in isolation, but they can be used with `break` and `continue` statements.

Comment: I would add that `they can be used` but they should not be used ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well... Because it's a valid `Java` code.

If you ask about `abc:System.out.println(9);` the `abc` is just a label for a label statement which is legal in Java however if you have to use it, it means, that your code went wrong.

They are most often used for labeling the nested loops:

```
abc: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         for (int j = i; j < 10; j ++) {
             if (j == 4) {
                break abc; //breaks the outer loop.
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Now I remember using it with goto statement. But since its no longer used, went out of my mind. Thanks for the answers folks. Appreciate!